# ContextNotActiveException when OmniFaces ViewScoped bean is injected in servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, cdi, omnifaces, view-scope

I've just updated a SessionScoped bean to OmniFaces (1.6.1) ViewScoped.  Everything seems to work except for the fact that I get the following Exception when my backing bean is injected into a Servlet that I'm using for the processing of an ajax request:

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped
```

Some things to consider:

1) The reason I have to inject a backing bean into a servlet is because I'm using jQuery's DataTables plugin, which (for server-side processing tables) requires an ajax request to retrieve table data.  So basically I can't use Primefaces' `<p:remoteCommand..>` or anything like that.

2) From what I can tell, there aren't any extra GET requests to the view that would destroy and recreate the backing bean.

Is there anything else that could cause this Exception?  Also, if this can't be done, is there another way to achieve what I'm doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@ViewScoped` annotation ties the bean to a specific JSF view which in turn relies on the presence of `FacesContext#getViewRoot()` and subsequently `UIViewRoot#getViewMap()`. None of both are available in a "plain vanilla" servlet. There's no means of a JSF view inside a plain servlet request, let alone a JSF context. So, unfortunately, this behavior is "by design".

You've basically 2 options:

1. Store the desired shared information in the session scope which is keyed by an unique key which is passed around as HTTP request parameter so that both the JSF managed bean and the servlet can grab it from the session scope.

   E.g. in JSF backing bean:

   ```java
   dataId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   externalContext.getSessionMap().put(dataId, data);
   ```

   In JSF view:

   ```html
   <h:outputScript>var dataId = "#{bean.dataId}";</h:outputScript>
   ```

   In JavaScript:

   ```js
   function loadData() {
       $.get("servletURL", { dataId: dataId }, function(response) {
           // ...
       });
   }
   ```

   In servlet:

   ```java
   String dataId = request.getParameter("dataId");
   Data data = (Data) session.getAttribute(dataId);
   ```

   ---
2. Use a true JSF backing bean instead of a plain vanilla servlet. You can definitely use `<p:remoteCommand>` for that. You can use `RequestContext#addCallbackParam()` in action(listener) method to "pass" ("print" is technically more correct) a JSON object from Java to JS and finally use `oncomplete` attribute to process it. Given that you're using OmniFaces, the [`<o:commandScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript) and [`Ajax#data()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax) offers the same functionality. The `Ajax#data()` has the additional advantage that it automatically converts from Java to JSON so that you don't need to do it yourself.

   E.g. in JSF view:

   ```html
   <o:commandScript name="loadData" action="#{bean.loadData}" oncomplete="processData()" />
   ```

   In JSF backing bean:

   ```
   public void loadData() {
       Ajax.data(data);
   }
   ```

   In JavaScript:

   ```js
   function processData() {
       var data = OmniFaces.Ajax.data;
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem with #2 is that the javascript that sends the request is sent by the datatables plugin.  So to set it up I would do something like this how is described here: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html.  So I don't know if I can call a loadData() method.  I'd either have to ditch the plugin and rewrite how the table works, or go with #1 as you suggest, which is probably the approach I'll have to take.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I'm not familiar with that (`<p:dataTable>` with lazy data model is much easier), but couldn't you just give it the function name it needs to invoke?

Comment: When instantiating the plugin, one of the options is a url passed as a string, which the plugin uses to invoke the ajax request.  So I don't think passing a function would work (unless it does work and I've missed that in the documentation). I'll give it a try.

Comment: @BalusC In Version 2 of your answer, Shouldn't it be in Javascrpit `var data = OmniFaces.Ajax.loadData` or is `OmniFaces.Ajax.data` predefined name ?